# connect from web to iot core using a custom authorizer

Tags: iot, aws-sdk-js, aws-iot-core

I'm trying to use a custom authorizer to authenticate a web client.
I have succesfully created a dedicated lambda and a custom authorizer. If I launch `aws iot describe-authorizer --authorizer-name <authorizer-name>` I can see

```json
{
    "authorizerDescription": {
        "authorizerName": "<authorizer-name>",
        "authorizerArn": "...",
        "authorizerFunctionArn": "...",
        "tokenKeyName": "<token-key-name>",
        "tokenSigningPublicKeys": {
            "<public-key-name>": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n<public-key-content>\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
        },
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "creationDate": "...",
        "lastModifiedDate": "...",
        "signingDisabled": false,
        "enableCachingForHttp": false
    }
}
```

Moreover I can test it succesfully:

```bash
$ aws iot test-invoke-authorizer --authorizer-name '<authorizer-name>' --token '<public-key-name>' --token-signature '<private-key-content>'
{
    "isAuthenticated": true,
    "principalId": "...",
    "policyDocuments": [ "..." ],
    "refreshAfterInSeconds": 600,
    "disconnectAfterInSeconds": 3600
}
$
```

But I cannot connect using the browser.

I'm using aws-iot-device-sdk and [according the SDK documentation](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js#custom-authorization-configuration) I should set `customAuthHeaders` and/or `customAuthQueryString` (my understanding is that the latter should be used in web environment due to a limitation of the browsers) with the headers / queryparams `X-Amz-CustomAuthorizer-Name`, `X-Amz-CustomAuthorizer-Signature` and `TestAuthorizerToken` but no matter what combination I set for these values the iot endpoint always close the connection (I see a 1000 / 1005 code for the closed connection)

What I've written so far is

```js
const CUSTOM_AUTHORIZER_NAME = '<authorizer-name>';
const CUSTOM_AUTHORIZER_SIGNATURE = '<private-key-content>';
const TOKEN_KEY_NAME = 'TestAuthorizerToken';
const TEST_AUTHORIZER_TOKEN = '<public-key-name>';


function f(k: string, v?: string, p: string = '&'): string {
    if (!v)
        return '';
    return `${p}${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(v)}`;
}

const client = new device({
            region: '...',
            clientId: '...',
            protocol: 'wss-custom-auth' as any,
            host: '...',
            debug: true,
            // customAuthHeaders: {
            //     'X-Amz-CustomAuthorizer-Name': CUSTOM_AUTHORIZER_NAME,
            //     'X-Amz-CustomAuthorizer-Signature': CUSTOM_AUTHORIZER_SIGNATURE,
            //     [TOKEN_KEY_NAME]: TEST_AUTHORIZER_TOKEN
            // },
            customAuthQueryString: `${f('X-Amz-CustomAuthorizer-Name', CUSTOM_AUTHORIZER_NAME, '?')}${f('X-Amz-CustomAuthorizer-Signature', CUSTOM_AUTHORIZER_SIGNATURE)}${f(TOKEN_KEY_NAME, TEST_AUTHORIZER_TOKEN)}`,
        } as any);
```

As you can see I started having also doubts about the headers names!

After running my code I see that the client tries to do a GET to the host with the querystring that I wrote.
I also see that IoT core responds with a `101 Switching Protocols`, and then that my client send the `CONNECT` command to IoT via websocket and then another packet from my browser to the backend system.
Then the connection is closed by IoT.
Looking at cloudwatch I cannot see any interaction with the lambda, it's like the request is blocked.

my doubts are:

- first of all, is it *possible* to connect via mqtt+wss using *only* a custom auth, without cognito/certificates? keep in mind that I am able to use a cognito identity pool without errors, but I need to remove it.
- is it correct that I just need to set up the `customAuthQueryString` parameter? my understanding is that this should be used on the web.
- what *are* the values I should set up for the various headers/queryparams? `X-Amz-CustomAuthorizer-Name` is self explanatory, but I'm not sure about `X-Amz-CustomAuthorizer-Signature` (it's correct to fill it with the content of my private key?). moreover I'm not sure about the `TestAuthorizerToken`. Is it the correct key to set up?

I've also tried to run the [custom_authorizer_connect of the sdk v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js-v2/tree/main/samples/browser/custom_authorizer_connect) but it's still not working, and I run out of ideas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

turns out the problem was in the permissions set on the backend systems.